# equal spacing for 'ordinary' limit and one-sided limit

Tags: amsmath

The problem is that one-sided limits have subscripted symbols above `$a$`. I tried adding a blank subscript to the 'ordinary' limit, but that didn't seem to even out spacing.

```
\underline{Theorem:} $\lim \limits_{x \to a^{}} f(x)
\Longleftrightarrow \lim \limits_{x \to a^{-}} f(x)
= \lim \limits_{x \to a^{+}} f(x)$
```

Comment: You would use a "phantom" glyph, as in  `\limits_{x \to a^{\phantom{-}}}` to leave extra space in the ordinary limit, but I don't like the look of it at all.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but it seems like you are missing the word "exists".

Answer (score 4):

Use `\vphantom{+}` to have the same height as the RHS.

```
\underline{Theorem:} $\lim\limits_{x \to a^{\vphantom{+}}} f(x)
\Longleftrightarrow \lim\limits_{x \to a^{-}} f(x)
= \lim\limits_{x \to a^{+}} f(x)$
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possibility, but takes a lot of work to get there.  It uses the `\vphantom` mentioned by AboAmmar, but it also horizontally centers the `\to` under the `\lim`.

It does it by placing a phantom scripted `-` to the left of the one-sided limits.  But then it must also introduce `\!\!\!` negative space to compensate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\underline{Theorem:} $\lim \limits_{x \to a^{\vphantom{-}}} f(x)
\Longleftrightarrow \!\!\!\lim \limits_{^{\phantom{-}}x \to a^{-}} f(x)
= \!\!\!\lim \limits_{^{\phantom{-}}x \to a^{+}} f(x)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If `a` is a constant, I'd suggest you use `\uparrow` and `\downarrow` to indicate unambiguously that the `x` is supposed to approach `a` from below and above, respectively. A very nice side-effect of this notation is that `x\uparrow a` and `x\downarrow a` take up less space than `x\to a` -- obviating any need to make spacing adjustments.

If, in addition, you wish to assure that `x\to a` and `x\uparrow a` (and `x\downarrow a`) are typeset at same distance below "lim", just change `x\to a` to `x\to a\vphantom{\uparrow}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
\lim_{x\to a} f(x)\Longleftrightarrow
\lim_{x\uparrow a} f(x)=
\lim_{x\downarrow a} f(x)$
\end{document}
```